# Kernel module compilation fails (gcc: error: elf_x86_64: No such file or directory)

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc

I'm trying to compile a simple kernel module, but the compilation fails due to a wrong argument passed by `make` to `gcc`.

This is the `Makefile`:

```
obj-m += test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) test
```

Running `make` produces the following errors:

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/build M=/home/user/test test
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-generic'
gcc   -m elf_x86_64  /home/user/test/test.c   -o test
gcc: error: elf_x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m’
make[1]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425761/kernel-compile-error-gcc-error-elf-i386-no-such-file-or-directory) answer doesn't help: I've searched all files within `/usr` for those containing `-m elf_x86` using `grep -rnw '/usr' -e "-m elf_x86"` and no file matches, so I have no idea about which file I need to edit to redefine `make`'s behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your own module makefile.

Kernel build makefiles are a little different from regular makefiles: the target needs to be `modules`, not the name of your module (`test`), which only needs to be specified via the `obj-m` variable:

```
obj-m += test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Comment: You're welcome - fwiw I don't actually know why using the module name causes that particular error.